# Button appearance not updating on class change

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

When a button is clicked, its background-color does not become yellow as intended nor does the previously clicked button's background-color revert to red. My goal is to change the buttons' colors when they are clicked by changing their classes. When the buttons' classes are changed they do not change color. The purpose of testFunction() is updating the color of the buttons. The purpose of testFunction2() is adding an onclick function to the buttons.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<style>
    .button {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .c {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="test1">
                <button class="c">0</button>
                <button class="">1</button>
                <button class="">2</button>
                <button class="">3</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="test2">
                <button class="c">0</button>
                <button>1</button>
                <button>2</button>
                <button>3</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        var lastClick1 = 0;
        var lastClick2 = 0;
        //alert('js');
        function testFunction(c, n) {
            //  alert('tf');
            if (c == 0) {
                //  alert('s=0');
                if (lastClick1 != n) {
                    var a = document.getElementById("test1").children;
                    a[lastClick1].class = '';
                    a[n].class = 'c';
                    alert('n: ' + n + ' class: ' + a[n].class);
                    alert('lastclick:' + lastClick1 + ' class: ' + a[lastClick1].class);
                    lastClick1 = n;
                }
            } else {
                //  alert('else');
                if (lastClick2 != n) {
                    var b = document.getElementById("test2").children;
                    b[lastClick2].class = '';
                    b[n].class = 'c';
                    alert('n: ' + n + ' class: ' + b[n].class);
                    alert('lastclick:' + lastClick2 + ' class: ' + b[lastClick2].class);
                    lastClick2 = n;
                }
            }
        }

        function testFunction2() {
            //alert('tf2');
            var t1 = document.getElementById("test1").children;
            var t2 = document.getElementById("test2").children;
            //alert(t1);
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                t1[i].onclick = function() {
                    testFunction(0, parseInt(this.innerText));
                };
                t2[i].onclick = function() {
                    testFunction(1, parseInt(this.innerText));
                };
            }
        }

        testFunction2();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to jQuery

[link](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js)

CSS

```
.button {
    background-color: red;
}

.c {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.r{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent('td').children('.c').removeClass('c').addClass('r');

        $(this).addClass('c');
    })
});
```